# Icono en Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

Alguien sabe que comando debo usar para poner un icono, dentro de la barra de navegación de la pagina que cree... He usado la sentencia básica de html sobre el template base, pero sin éxito.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione:

Por si alguien más lo necesita, dentro de su archivo base, lo único que deben de agregar es:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'core/img/favicon.ico' %}">
```

donde `favicon.ico` es el nombre del icono que desean cargar y `core/img` la ruta donde han guardado este archivo donde su proyecto.

¡Saludos!